# How can I scale the size of a sprite in Phaser/PixiJS without changing its position?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, pixi.js

I'm making a game in Phaser using some large images that I want to scale down in the actual game:

```
create() {
    //Create the sprite group and scale it down to 30%
    this.pieces = this.add.group(undefined, "pieces", true);
    this.pieces.scale.x = 0.3;
    this.pieces.scale.y = 0.3;

    //Add the players to the middle of the stage and add them to the 'pieces' group
    var middle = new Phaser.Point( game.stage.width/2, game.stage.height/2);
    var player_two = this.add.sprite(middle.x - 50, middle.y, 'image1', undefined, this.pieces);
    var player_one = this.add.sprite(middle.x, middle.y-50, 'image2', undefined, this.pieces);
}
```

However because the sprites are scaled in size, *their starting location is also scaled*, so instead appearing in the middle of the stage, they appear only 30% of the distance to the middle.

How do I scale the sprite image without it affecting their location?

(The code is incidentally in Typescript but I think this particular sample is also javascript so that's probably irrelevant)

Answer (score 12):

Set Sprite.anchor to 0.5 so the physics body is centered on the Sprite, scale the sprite image without it affecting their location.

```
this.image.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
```

- [Doc Phaser.Image](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Image.html)
- [Anchor example](http://examples.phaser.io/_site/view_full.html?d=sprites&f=anchor.js&t=anchor)

Answer (score 10):

You can scale your sprite like so:

```
var scaleX = 2;
var scaleY = 2;    
sprite.scale.set(scaleX, scaleY);
```

then calculate position of sprite:

```
 var positionX = 100;
 var positionY = 100;

 sprite.x = positionX / scaleX;
 sprite.y = positionY / scaleY;
```

Now your sprite is at position (100, 100).
The problem is that `sprite.x` got multiplied by with `scaleX`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Phaser, I'd like to add that in the specific case of weapon.bullets or other groups you create yourself you're going to have to do it this way instead:

```
weapon.bullets.setAll('scale.x', 0.5);
weapon.bullets.setAll('scale.y', 0.5);
```

I got stuck on this and ended up in this thread, which is closed but in my case just not what I needed. Others will hopefully have some use out of this :)